# How to resize bimpat size?

Tags: android

In my application I need to resize the bitmap to imageview size. I tried the following code and I am getting exception.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), aMatrix, false);
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, MyImageview_wt, MyImageview_ht, false);
MyImageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Pls help

Thanks
Monali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code

```
public static Bitmap resizeBitMapImage1(String filePath, int targetWidth,
            int targetHeight) {
        Bitmap bitMapImage = null;
        // First, get the dimensions of the image
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        double sampleSize = 0;
        // Only scale if we need to
        // (16384 buffer for img processing)
        Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math
                .abs(options.outWidth - targetWidth);

        if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 1638) {
            // Load, scaling to smallest power of 2 that'll get it <= desired
            // dimensions
            sampleSize = scaleByHeight ? options.outHeight / targetHeight
                    : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
            sampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2d,
                    Math.floor(Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
        }

        // Do the actual decoding
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[128];
        while (true) {
            try {
                options.inSampleSize = (int) sampleSize;
                bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    sampleSize = sampleSize * 2;
                } catch (Exception ex1) {

                }
            }
        }

        return bitMapImage;
    }
```

Comment: I got the original image size

Comment: My Imageview is of 300x300 and my bitmap size is 200x200 and I want to resize it to 300x300..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the width and height of the Bitmap itself, but instead you want to get the Height and Width of your ImageView and resize your Bitmap acordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), aMatrix, false);
bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, MyImageview_wt, MyImageview_ht, false);
MyImageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```