# Need help in handling images in android

Tags: android

I am implementing an android application in which I am attaching images to issues. These attachments are of two types,

attachment by using camera
attachment of photo from gallery (already existing photo in gallery)
I am getting these Images as follows,

```
//Camera Request
Intent captureImage = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

captureImage.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
startActivityForResult(captureImage, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

// Gallery Pic request
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);
```

The result of above is URI. And I am saving this uri.getPath() in my database.

Now problem is when I want to show these images I am fetching it with the help of uri I am having. But I am getting an exception after loading first image; java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

I read some blogs and I came to know that memory is insufficient for loading it.

Is anybody having working solution on compressing images while showing them in a list And recycle memory used after work is done??

Comment: but can you tell me why you store uri.getpath in database?

Comment: I feel you have to resize the image. [Look here How to resize.][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488878/how-to-resize-bimpat-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                                        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

                                        int width = display.getWidth();
                                        int height = display.getHeight();


                                        int bitmap_width = photoBitmap.getWidth();
                                        int bitmap_height = photoBitmap.getHeight();
    // where photoBitmap is your Bitmap image                                   

                                        if(bitmap_width >width)
                                            bitmap_width = width ;

                                        if(bitmap_height>height)
                                         bitmap_height = height ;


// compressing bitmap goes here
                                        photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (photoBitmap, width, height, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will run out of memory if you are loading or downloading a large amount of data and storing it directly in the heap space. You can avoid this by loading your data in chunks and/or cacheing it. Also, remove objects that are no longer in use as they will take up part of your memory as long as there is a reference to them. You can also resize bitmaps to a smaller size to save space as you go along.

You should assume your maximum heap size to be 16 MB, as that is the limit set by Android for some of the older versions, even though devices running the newer versions of Android may have a higher heap size. Alternatively, you could get a guide for your memory limit by using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass().

Answer (score 0):

You will run out of memory if you are loading or downloading a large amount of data and storing it directly in the heap space. You can avoid this by loading your data in chunks and/or cacheing it. Also, remove objects that are no longer in use as they will take up part of your memory as long as there is a reference to them. You can also resize bitmaps to a smaller size to save space as you go along.